# Active Admin checkboxes are not active when in edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, formtastic

I am working to build out an admin using active admin. One thing I am running into is the use of listing out nested models with check boxes and the checkbox being selected IF its one of the ids on the current model being edited.

Right now I m using something like:

`f.input :subcategory, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Subcategory.all`

Which lists all of the subcategories. Even when I check them it shows them stored on the show view after I click update. But when I hit edit again the check box that I clicked is now inactive and not persisting the data.

Is there another flag that needs to be added to that line for these to show?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your server log. Probably you forgot to add a `subcategory` in `attr_accessible`.